# Custom Calendar View With Overflowing Event in android

Tags: java, android

[image]I have to create one Custom Calendar in which Events are Overflowing from One Day to another. How to create such layout in android.
For Example Event **test2** starts on 16th and ends on 19th. I have to create such overflowing event.
I have created Custom Calendar and adding Events but the Event text is getting repeated on each date.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: search here 
https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui